# Databricks parquet conversion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, databricks

I am doing parquet conversion using databricks. The file is  ^A delimited. I am mentioning this explicitly when creating a DF as shown below. However when i get a ^M character within the data, it terminated there and gives a malformed line exception. Can someone please suggest how do i handle this?

**sample part from the record**:
  Rollout^Asome text comes here;^M ^M Rewards:somemore text;^A0.00

```
val dataframe = sparkSession.sqlContext.read
                    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                    .option("delimiter", "\U0001")
                    .option("header", "false")
                    .option("mode","FAILFAST")
                    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls","true")
                    .option("nullValue"," ")
                    .option("quote","")
                    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
                    .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
                    .schema(schema)
                    .load(fileLocation)
```

**ERROR**
Malformed line in FAILFAST mode: Rollout^Asome text comes here;

Answer (score 1):

you can get the `dataframe` by using `sparkContext` too as below

```
val dataframe = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile(fileLocation).map(line => line.split("\\^A")).map(array => (array(0).trim, array(1).trim, array(2).trim)).toDF

dataframe.show(false)
```

Output is

```
+-------+-------------------------------------------------+----+
|_1     |_2                                               |_3  |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------+----+
|Rollout|some text comes here;^M ^M Rewards:somemore text;|0.00|
+-------+-------------------------------------------------+----+
```

**Updated**

You have commented

> > But we are building a generic framework which handle 1000+ tables and we are looking for a more generic solution

for that you can *create a schema* and *use that schema to create a dataframe*. I have tried to make as much generic as I could

```
//read the file
val rdd = sc.textFile(fileLocation).map(line => line.split("\\^A"))
//create schema
val schema = StructType(rdd.first().indices.map(x => StructField("col_"+(x+1), StringType)))

//create dataframe
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.map(Row.fromSeq(_)), schema).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-----+
|col_1  |col_2                                            |col_3|
+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-----+
|Rollout|some text comes here;^M ^M Rewards:somemore text;|0.00 |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-----+
```

So now *the column numbers depends on how many `^A` you have in data*

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks for your reply
But  we are building a generic framework which handle 1000+ tables and we are looking for a more generic solution

Comment: @user8062565, I have updated my answer . I hope I answered it correctly this time ;) I took me 1 year to figure out it :)